# battery discharges in a strange way on Lenovo Ideapad Z500

Tags: 13.10, laptop, power-management, lenovo, battery

I've a Lenovo ideapad Z500 laptop with Windows only energy management software (my battery stop charging at 60% for long lasting life).
Setting the threshold from Windows, it remains also with Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit, and that's ok.

- In my case, battery is discharged in a strange way: it takes 30 minutes for consuming it from 60% to 40%, and then it suddenly drops to 5% in one second.
- This behaviour is the same with various tools: laptop mode tools, TLP, powertop.

I'm using Bumblebee for dual gpu management (intel + nvidia), Gpu temperature is < 50° in normal situation.
What can I do for obtaining a longer battery duration? I explored some options but no results.. - Thanks and sorry for my poor English

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you calibrated the battery recently?  After a while they need recalibrated by doing a full 100% charge, discharge to < 5%, recharge to 100% cycle.

Comment: no, never done calibration. Is there a software for doing this? Because now the battery stop charging at 60%, and I don't know how to change these tresholds

Comment: thank you for this answer, it worked! I rebooted into windows and run the lenovo software for battery calibration! Now my battery duration is better: about 1,5 hours. Thanks (PS I'm sorry but I can't vote up you answer because my reputation is low)

Comment: @Cirux, does it now go from 100% down to 5% correctly?  It sounds like that software had the battery report 5% to cause a low power shutdown because you configured it to only use 40-60%.  Best to let it go all the way up and down, and just try to avoid running it down below 20-40% if you can help it for long life.  Taking it all the way down occasionally won't hurt much; just try to plug it back in before it gets down to 20% most of the time.

Comment: yes, now battery discharges slowly :-). I'm still using the Lenovo option for charging only until 60%: on windows is indicated "plugged, not charging" on ubuntu is indicated "in phase of charge" but it remains at 59%. I'm often plugged at power source and battery isn't removable. Does it means that the battery is always charging? Or is not charging but ubuntu software can't manage it? Maybe I risk some damage? Thank you

Comment: @Cirux I up voted for you. I also like the answer.

Answer (score 0):

for charging upto 100%,go to lenovo energy management>change battery setting to 'maximum battery life'.In 'optimized battery health' the charging is locked to 60%,after 60% in will show plugged in,not charging

Answer (score -1):

Most laptops do this in Ubuntu, when the battery is dying. Ubuntu can not see what cells are still working so it suddenly takes a jump downwards when it gets to a cell thats not working. The reason why Windows does not do this, is that Windows takes the "100% battery" over the working cells only, not the complete amount of cells in the battery.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but I think battery is not dying.. this laptop was bought on August 2013

Comment: That doesn't really mean the battery isn't dying, just that it's not as likely to be dying. Defective stuff gets shipped out of every factory in the world. Also, Dan Johansen might have meant that the charge in the battery is dying, not the battery itself. Perhaps he'll clarify.

Comment: No... it is the battery itself that reports its capacity; neither OS looks at individual cells.

Comment: anyway, with Windows 8 my laptop has about 2,5 hours of autonomy with the battery charged at 60%, so at 99% chances is not a defective battery